# How can banks & credit cards fall victim to what seems obvious fraud?

Tags: credit-card, fraud

I'm trying to identify the company that is a payee on my credit card statement where fraudulent transactions were paid, but I'm having a difficult time. There are a couple of scams that have abbreviated names of companies with a non-working telephone number attached, e.g., Amazon might appear as Amzn or something similar with a unique scrambled code next to it and a phone number that is disconnected, .e.g. Amzn 34X34YRH 730-000-1010. The number looks legit but is disconnected. The processors are a major ones (like Square.)

I was just told (by the bank - a tier 1) that the merchant name may not be accurate and that telephone number is optional. This strikes me as odd. Before I begin the journey to reach the payee, I'm trying to determine who that is.

1. Let's assume the company listed is the real company, Amazon. How does it slip past the payment processor that the phone number is non-working, especially when I'm reading literally hundreds of complaints about it and probably more? At some point someone has to know about this as the defrauded should be able to know who charged your card and how to reach them.
2. Second case is it's not the company it seems. I was told that companies can put in names that aren't actually their corporate name or the agreement they signed up to use. So some company can type in AMZN as the charging company but it's not confirmed. While that might slip through cracks with small fraud, I can't see this happening on a mass scale, especially if impersonating a larger company like the Amazon example I gave above. This doesn't make sense to me.

I need to know because if it is the real big company, trying to get customer support is horrific. Unless there is a specific charge to your card you can reference, good luck trying to find someone. I'm hoping someone can help provide some insight. There are hundreds of examples of the same fraud warnings online.

Comment: `Before I begin the journey to reach the payee, I'm trying to determine who that is` - what for? What are you trying to do?

Comment: What’s your point?  Is there a fraudulent charge on your card, or not?

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're actually trying to accomplish here, besides blowing off stream. If it was as easy and cheap as you assume, banks and companies would already be doing it. But a dirty little secret of business in general is that sometimes preventing a problem would cost more than refunding the customer,  and banking is a business.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't a personal finance question.

Answer (score 7):

## Fraud Warnings

**Don't necessarily believe generic fraud warnings written online by people you don't know.** This includes people you know passing on "warnings" that they have read online. There are people out there (called "trolls") who will propagate false warnings in order to stir up chaos. They would love nothing more than to convince millions of people that their genuine credit card charges from Amazon are false, and flood the credit card companies with false reports. If you are seeing the same "warnings" over a long period of time that's a good indication they are false. Real fraudsters get taken down pretty quickly - or at least change their form.

**If you have a specific transaction that you believe is fraudulent** (or just a mistake) **talk to the credit card company, not the company that charged it.** They will investigate the specifics of that transaction. The company name and phone number on the transaction will be irrelevant.

## The Phone Number

There are millions of organizations that are set up to charge to credit cards. The record appears different for each one. In fact for chain stores a credit card use at different branches will show up with different text in the record. In short this means there is no practical way for a credit card company to validate the phone number. Even if they did, it's absolutely possible for a fraudulent company to set up a temporary phone number, answer it when the credit company calls and confirm the details, and then shut it down. Even if they didn't shut it down, no calls about fraudulent transactions are going to be answered.

## The Name

It's going to be similarly hard to police a "similar" name. A company that sells products from the Brazilian rainforest may well be legitimately called "Amazon" and certainly "Amzn" would be allowed. Again it's going to be really hard to police that.

## The Scale

Do you have any reason to think that this "Amzn" company is defrauding millions of people over a long time? The pattern with most out-and-out fraudsters is that they get in quickly, make as many fraudulent charges in as short a time as possible, and then get out before anybody can do anything about it. It's not happening "on a mass scale" - or rather it's lots of individual fraudsters doing it on a small scale. If you are seeing the same company defrauding you over a long timescale then something else is going on. Online posts claiming a particular form of transaction record or particular phone number is being fraudulently used over a long period are probably false.

The way fraudsters like this are dealt with is if enough people report a fraud then the credit card company will cut them off. If they are doing nothing but fraudulent transactions then then can be cut off very quickly.

> Unless there is a specific charge to your card you can reference, good luck trying to find someone.

Unless you have a specific fraudulent charge to your credit card, then there doesn't appear to be anything for you to complain about. Don't try to call companies because you have read somewhere that they might be defrauding someone.

## Edit

According to some of your comments, your problem appears to be that you are seeing some transactions you didn't make charged to a major company. They have all been reversed by the credit card firm.

If this is happening repeatedly it almost certainly isn't the fault of the major company. Instead someone has stolen your credit card details and is using them to purchase stuff from this company. If a purchase is made from the company with all the correct credit card details, then the company cannot be expected to know that it's not you making the transaction. It's certainly not "obvious fraud" as you call it.

If you are seeing repeated fraudulent transactions like this then you should cancel your card and get a new one. If you have cancelled you card and are seeing unauthorised transactions on the new card too then one of a few things is happening. Either:

1. Someone has access to all your credit cards on an ongoing basis. Are there other people in your house? Consider locking your credit cards somewhere.
2. You are repeatedly using your cards at a business (probably small) which is dishonest or has a dishonest employee who steals your card info. Talk to the credit card firm about this. Reduce your credit card use at small businesses, especially if there is a business that takes your physical card. Consider using cash there instead.
3. A business (probably online) that stores your card info has a dishonest employee. This is actually extremely unlikely. Delete your card info from any websites where you have stored them, and change your card. Don't allow websites to store your card info - enter it each time.
4. You have subscribed to a service (such as Amazon Prime perhaps?) and the subscription has been rolled over to your new card. If that might be the case explicitly cancel the subscription, and if it continues talk to your credit card provider to get the subscription stopped. (Thanks @Nelson)

In any case, knowing the phone number of the business where the transaction was made will not help you in the slightest.

Comment: Thank you for trying to answer the post but it seems you're not understanding the issue and it is happening on a mass scale. The net result is the phone number associated with the major vendor likely hasn't been updated in many years.

The absurd inform I received was from a top tier bank. Perhaps the weekend employee was not tops in the support team. My charges were all refunded a week earlier and it is remarkable the unusual charge pattern evaded detection.

Comment: Users of the vendor are likely entering stolen credit card details. The non-working phone number has been on victim statements for so long results that people  are incorrectly associating it with a  scam company - the same as you are assuming here. I've confirmed the merchant name and format is bona fide. It was also their # for years. People were calling the phone number for at least 1+ years, getting no response, assuming it's a scam company.  But it's not.

Thanks for the post but people should have some patience before downvoting furiously that something must be impossible.

Comment: If we aren't understanding the question, edit it to make it clear what you are asking. So far your only complaint appears to be that some credit card transactions include a phone number that is out of date. But all your problems have been resolved by the credit card company, so you have no reason to contact the vendor company.

Comment: To the answer. (Slip of the keyboard.)

Comment: I added some paragraphs to the answer to address what you seem to be saying.

Comment: "the company cannot be expected to know that it's not you making the transaction"  Actually such companies can do a whole lot better about this.  Amazon knows if the same card number is already associated with another Amazon account.  That by itself isn't grounds to decline the transaction, but it absolutely would be a reason to send a notification through the other account, especially if it's a long-standing account which has been using that credit card repeatedly for an extended time.

Comment: You need to add one more point to the "repeating transactions" after changing cards. They signed up for a subscription. Changing cards will NOT cancel subscriptions (I worked as a software engineer setting up Point of Sale systems, so I know how this stuff works). When getting a new card, the customer support should explicitly ask why you are getting a new card and you should explicitly tell them that you suspect fraud, so that they can cancel all the subscriptions. If your card happens to be expiring and you got a new card that way, it will **not** cancel subscriptions.

Comment: @Nelson So the subscription will be charged and the credit card company will pass it on to the new card?

Comment: @DJClayworth Yes. Modern PCI compliant payment processors will NEVER give the vendor any of your CC information. They're also not suppose to see any of it. At all. When you sign up for a subscription, the vendor receives a subscription code that uniquely represents you as the customer. When a credit card is replaced, your subscription code stays the same (since you're still the same customer), and your subscriptions will get linked to the new card automatically, UNLESS the replacement card is explicitly to counter fraud, then it breaks all subscriptions.

Comment: It's not just trolls that pass on dubious warnings. Some people are credulous, worrywarts, or just think they are doing their friends a favor by passing on such warnings.

Comment: Yes. The trolls create the fakes and the credulous or scared pass them on.